# How to automatically update the changes of specific value in another sheet in excel

Tags: excel

your help is highly appreciated.
So this is my data:

[image]

And from the above data, if I add a row of value a 5, then it should get update in another sheet from 3 to 5.

[image]

Comment: Why?  What correlation exists?  Why is `a` 3 and `b` 4?  And why would the `3` become `5`?

Comment: There is no correlation, I just have to update the reflected change value of a in the other sheet

Comment: What is the rule.  Is it the max number?  The last number?  You need to explain better why you want to return the number you want to return.  Is there a date column that can be referenced or are we to assume it never gets sorted?

Comment: I just have to return the latest value of 'a', if the number does not equals with previous value of 'a'.

Comment: Latest would intonate that their is a date associated with it, I do not see any date column.  Are we to assume the lowest entry is the latest and that the table never gets sorted?

Comment: I only have this much information, there is no date associated with it.

Comment: Look into XLOOKUP, it has a setting to look from the bottom up so it will return the lowest match.  If you do not have XLOOKUP, then use INDEX/AGGREGATE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, xlookup has done it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Excel 365 then you can use an Index/Match formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(2,1/FIND(G2,$A$2:$A$7)))
```

If you have XLOOKUP you can use that:

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,"No Match",0,-1)
```